# Why would SQL truncate the right-side of a string when using the right function?

Tags: sql, oledb, visual-foxpro, dbase

I have a database with MANY out-of-date file locations. The difference between the out-of-date file locations and the correct locations is simply the left-side of the address. So, I am attempting to take the left-side off and replace it with the correct string. But, I can't get there because my query is altering the right-side of the address.

This query is made using "vfpoledb."

```
SELECT RIGHT(LINK,LEN(LINK)-8) ,LEN(LINK)-8,RIGHT(LINK,77),LINK 
FROM LINKSTORE 
WHERE DOCLBL = "V46145002A"
```

This query returns the following:

EXP1:

```
\SHARES\DATA\QMS\QMS DATA\TRACKING FILES\REMOTEENTRIES\V46145 216447
```

EXP2:

```
 77
```

EXP3:

```
\SHARES\DATA\QMS\QMS DATA\TRACKING FILES\REMOTEENTRIES\V46145 216447-002A.PDF
```

LINK:

```
\\SERVER\SHARES\DATA\QMS\QMS DATA\TRACKING FILES\REMOTEENTRIES\V46145 216447-002A.PDF
```

I don't understand why EXP1 and EXP3 are giving different results. EXP3 is what I'm looking for EXP1 to return. If I could get that, I could append the correct left-hand-side and create an update query to fix everything.

*Edit:*

Even when changing the query to:

```
SELECT RIGHT(LINK,LEN(LINK)) ,LEN(LINK)-8,RIGHT(LINK,77),LINK 
FROM LINKSTORE 
WHERE DOCLBL = "V46145002A"
```

The link still cuts off at the same point, which is odd because expression_3 which still uses `Right()`, but manually provides the length instead of using `Len()` does not do this.

Furthermore, it seems that when I run the query to include all results:

```
SELECT RIGHT(LINK,LEN(LINK)) ,LEN(LINK)-8,RIGHT(LINK,77),LINK 
FROM LINKSTORE 
WHERE 1=1
```

All values returned by `Exp1` are equal in length even though `Exp2` and `Link` are different in size.

So back to the *problem*, how can I run a query to replace the left-side with the correct server if I can't separate them out?

Comment: whats the original value of Link for your example?

Comment: It’s weird, may be is related with the hyphen character. It’s just there where is truncated

Comment: @codeulike The original value is as shown under "Link."

Comment: @Pontnou I changed the individual entry and removed the dash and the truncation still occurs at the same point.

Comment: Main information missing : What is your RDBMS? Assuming it is SQL server but that is not clearly stated. "SQL" <> "SQL server"

Comment: I am using ADOdb with the VFPoleDB driver. I am not using an RDBMS. The data is held in old d-base (dbf) files.

Comment: SO it is difficult to reproduce (not everyone is using dbase). I tried [with SQL server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=37047d2b7efb91aaa029fa0fb98eea24) and as you cant see it works fine. Anyway I think your logic is not adapted here, its is better to use [SUBSTR()](http://www.dbase.com/help/String_Objects/IDH_SUBSTR_FUNC.htm) function for this case, because if you have strings of different size, your approach wont return what you want, SUBSTR will. So just do this :  `SUBSTR(LINK,8)`.

Comment: Thomas, it looks like you're correct. SUBSTR is much better. I must have misinterpreted the use of SUBSTR. I had originally looked into that and thought that length was a requirement, so I didn't continue forward.

Comment: A little further investigation and while `SUBSTR()` is much better, if you concatenate the result of `SUBSTR()` with another string, it actually does the same thing that is seen with `Right()`. Interesting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK this is tricky, I did some Foxpro 20 years ago but don't have it to hand.

Your SELECT statement looks OK to me. In the comments under the question Thomas G created this DbFiddle which shows that in a 'normal' dbms, your SELECT statement gives the result you are expecting: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=37047d2b7efb91aaa029fa0fb98eea24

So the problem must be something FoxPro/dBase specific rather than a problem with your SELECT statement.

Reading up I see people say that with FoxPro always use ALLTRIM() when using RIGHT() or LEN() on table fields because the data gets returned padded with spaces. I don't see how that would cause the exact bug you're seeing but you could try this maybe:

```
SELECT RIGHT(ALLTRIM(LINK),LEN(ALLTRIM(LINK))-8) ,LEN(ALLTRIM(LINK))-8,RIGHT(ALLTRIM(LINK),77),ALLTRIM(LINK)
FROM LINKSTORE 
WHERE DOCLBL = "V46145002A"
```

edit: OK I got a better idea - are there other rows in your result set?

According to this: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1706948 ... when you do SELECT (expr) in FoxPro whatever the length of the expr in the first row becomes that max length for that 'field' and so all subsequent rows get truncated to that length. Makes sense in a crazy 1970s sort of way.

So perhaps you have a row of data above the one we are talking about which comes out at 68 chars long and so every subsequent value gets truncated to that length.

The way around it is to pad your expression results with CAST or PADR:

```
SELECT PADR(RIGHT(ALLTRIM(LINK),LEN(ALLTRIM(LINK))-8),100),LEN(ALLTRIM(LINK))-8,PADR(RIGHT(ALLTRIM(LINK),77),100),LINK
    FROM LINKSTORE 
    WHERE DOCLBL = "V46145002A"
```

Or same without the ALLTRIM()

```
SELECT PADR(RIGHT(LINK,LEN(LINK)-8),100),LEN(LINK)-8,PADR(RIGHT(LINK,77),100),LINK
    FROM LINKSTORE 
    WHERE DOCLBL = "V46145002A"
```

Comment: You nailed it. Oddly, no I don't have more results in the set, but it seems FoxPro is trimming anyway. Perhaps it trims to the first result even if it doesn't fit the `where` statement? Because when I expand the results using `where 1=1` it matches what you're saying.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Thats interesting that it trims based on filtered out results - welcome to the 1970s I guess.

Comment: *Quietly proud of this answer to an obscure and apparently baffling question*

Comment: @codeulike _welcome to the 1970s_ is more the 1980s :-)